# Objective-C accessing / changing array elements in a multidimensional array (NSArray)

Tags: objective-c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to change a value in a multidimensional array but getting a compiler error:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of 'setValue:forKey:' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

This is my content array:

```
NSArray *tableContent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",nil],
                [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"d",@"e",@"f",nil],
                [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"g",@"h",@"i",nil],
                 nil];
```

This is how I'm trying to change the value:

```
[[tableContent objectAtIndex:0] setValue:@"new value" forKey:1];
```

**Solution:**

```
 [[tableContent objectAtIndex:0] setValue:@"new val" forKey:@"1"];
```

So the array key is a string type - kinda strange but good to know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *tableContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",nil],
                    [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"d",@"e",@"f",nil],
                    [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"g",@"h",@"i",nil],
                     nil];

[[tableContent objectAtIndex:0] replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"new object"];
```

You don't want to `alloc+init` for the sub-arrays because the retain count of the sub-arrays will be too high (+1 for the `alloc`, then +1 again as it is inserted into the outer array).

Answer (score 2):

You're creating immutable arrays, and trying to change the values stored in them.  Use NSMutableArray instead.

Answer (score 1):

You want either NSMutableArray's `insertObject:atIndex:` or `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` (the former will push the existing element back if one already exists, while the latter will replace it but doesn't work for indices that aren't already occupied). The message `setValue:forKey:` takes a value type for its first argument and an NSString for its second. You're passing an integer rather than an NSString, which is never valid.

Comment: There is no message like setObject:atIndex: but setObject:forKey:. But still get the same error.

Comment: There is no `setObject:atIndex:` for `NSMutableArray`, instead there is `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:`. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Apologies, posted while running out the door and made up a method. I've corrected to explain the two methods that I was conflating in my head.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for responding 1 and half years old question :D 
I got the same problem, and at last I solved it with counting the elements, then do `addObject` to push to the array element